# Function that returns a list of two elements in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

Is there a concise way to write in Haskell the function `(\x y -> x:y:[])` without using lambdas? For example, `(:[])` is much more elegant than `(\x -> [x])` or `(\x -> x:[])`.

Comment: this is necessarily a matter of opinion (and I've voted to close as such) - but personally I'd just go simple and unpretentious with `\x y -> [x, y]`. That strikes me personally as the most readable. (And needless to say I disagree with your second sentence. `\x -> [x]` is to me easily the most preferable of the 3 options you give - although I may well just use `pure` instead.)

Comment: It is not a matter of opinion: I'm asking if there exists a concise way to write this function without using lambdas.

Comment: You asked for a "better way".  "Better" implies a value judgment, hence opinion-based. As does your statement that `(:[])` is "much more elegant" - elegance is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: `(. return) . (:)` is concise, but unreadable. (Courtesy of pointfree.io)

Comment: I edited my question to make it objective.

Answer (score 6):

You can cook it up yourself with just a few standard tricks: write operators prefix to make application order more obvious, use `flip` to move arguments to the end, and `(.)` to pass results through. So:

```
\x y -> x:y:[]
= { prefix }
\x y -> (:) x ((:) y [])
= { move last argument to end of return value }
\x y -> (:) x (flip (:) [] y)
= { pass through results }
\x -> (:) x . flip (:) []
= { prefix }
\x -> (.) ((:) x) (flip (:) [])
= { move last argument to end of return value }
\x -> flip (.) (flip (:) []) ((:) x)
= { pass through results }
flip (.) (flip (:) []) . (:)
```

If you like, you can use sections to make the last one slightly more idiomatic:

```
= { elide flip using sections }
(. (:[])) . (:)
```

None of these is particularly concise. They are also all, in my opinion, significantly less readable than `\x y -> [x,y]`.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers have covered more direct ways but I would like to suggest

```
(++) `on` singleton
```

which is short while still being fairly easy to understand.

For me `singleton` is most readable but note it is not in the Haskell Report and is only in GHC since base 4.14.  Use `(:[])` or `pure` or `return` if you prefer.